# I can't pose my armature after setting a keyframe?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

I have been having problems rotating an armature after setting a keyframe. When I select a bone and hit R the armature actually moves, but as soon as I hit the left mouse button to set it to that position it returns to the position it was in the previous keyframe. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you provide your .blend file and add screenshots of the problem?

Comment: there are too many things that could have gone wrong, you are gonna have to recreate your problem and post your blendfile